# How to open modal from anywhere in the application

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I need to place all the modals in a single place so that I can access any modal from anywhere in the applicaion. Is this possible.

Now, I'm opening an modal in the below way.

```
openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>,cssClass:any) {
    if(this.modalRef) {
        this.closeModal();
    }
    this.config.class = cssClass;
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, this.config);
}
closeModal() {
    if(this.modalRef) {
        this.modalRef.hide();
        this.modalRef = null;
    }
}
```

and in my HTML

```
<button (click)="openModal(someModal,'some-class')">Click</button>

<ng-template #someModal> <div class="modal-body"> Login Here </div></ng-template>
```

I have tried in the following way 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wuntd3

HTML Element in my local
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom directive where you can access the modal anywhere from the application. Only the content of the modal will be differing w.r.t the context of the requirement.

Comment: Any example to achieve this

Comment: What Modal are you using so that I can help you to come up with the directive.

Comment: NullInjectorError: No provider for BsModalService! Try to resolve it. It will work fine with your approach

Comment: I'm unable to resolve this in stackblitz. I'm not facing this exception in my local. In my local i'm able to see the HTML for modal but there is no content in it. Pls see the attached image in my question

Comment: Where is the code, where you are adding the content. I could not see it. Only you are opening the modal, but not adding the content to it.

Comment: Yes. The content was there inside. But it is not showing there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170782/discussion-between-krishna-and-padmapriya-vishnuvardhan).

Answer (score -1):

> You can checkout @angular/cdk which is used to develop material design dialog, see [Portals and overlays](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview) and how you can use them to open a component as a dialog in another dom area. I think is the simplest way and has the most features using this you have the functionality which you want.